# Preloading Documents into iOS App

Tags: objective-c, ios, filesystems

**The Situation**:
I have an iOS app that deals with files and lets the user save, edit, open and perform various operations with these files. I'd like to be able to have some pre-made documents for the user to look at when they open the app (ex. a template) alongside their own custom documents.

**The Problem**:
How can I create a document (or template file) and have it appear in the Documents folder after the user installs my app and launches it (and all preceding times)?

**Background**:
This document (the one that'd be installed into the app's documents directory) is created by me, not the user.

I know that to do this you need to save it in your bundle, and then when your app runs for the first time silently copy it into the Documents Directory. Should I copy it in the appDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method or in my viewDidLoad method and write logic to detect if it's the first time the app has run?

**My Code**:
At this webpage: http://textsnip.com/d35fbc     
But when it runs, it always says: "File does not exist [in documents folder]", then it tells me that it's being copied. The problem is that when I examine the app's documents folder it is never there, it's still in the bundle.

Why won't it copy with this code
How does this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the files must in fact be added to the app bundle, then copied silently when the app launches.

The following code copies a text file from the top level of my bundle to the documents directory if it doesn't already exist.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *txtPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"txtFile.txt"];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:txtPath] == NO) {
    NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"txtFile" ofType:@"txt"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourcePath toPath:txtPath error:&error];
}
```

The only flaw in this code is that if the user deletes the file, it immediately reappears when they open the app again.

Answer (score 3):

As you said, you include it in your app bundle (add it to your project and make sure it's part of your target). Then you can access it's path by calling something like this:

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyTemplateDoc" 
                                                       ofType:@"extension"];
```

Then you copy it to your app's documents folder.

```
NSString *docPath = <a path in your documents folder>
NSError *error = nil;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:bundlePath 
                                        toPath:docPath 
                                         error:&error];
if (error) {
    // handle copy error.
}
```

Comment: I've put the following code in my viewDidLoad Method, but it never copies (I even found the iOS Simulator files on my Mac, and it isn;t there). Here is a link to the code: http://textsnip.com/d35fbc

Comment: When I run the app, the NSLog lines all execute as expected which tells me that it is being executed in the viewDidLoad method. But what was that you said about the Target? How do I add it to my Target?

Comment: Select the file and on the right side of XCode 4 (might have to open the right panel) in the first tab, make sure your target is selected.

Comment: I added the Target Membership to both the App and App Tests. I even tested the copying code with breakpoints, and it does not copy- could this have to do with the docPath or bundlePath?

Comment: You're checking for errors incorrectly. You're supposed to check that the return from the copyItemAtPath:… method is `nil` in which case the error parameter contains the actual error.