# Can you add files to an IPA that will show in iTunes File Sharing?

Tags: ios, ipa

Is it possible to create an IPA (for iOS) and include files that will appear in the iTunes File Sharing menu?  (I believe this is also called the application's document folder?)

For example, suppose to wanted to include a CFG file that could be copied/uploaded using iExplorer or iFunbox, or iTunes File Sharing, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preloading Documents into iOS App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745768/preloading-documents-into-ios-app)

Comment: As far as I know you can put them in  the bundle and export them to the icloud and then other apps could access via document picker https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/AccessingDocuments/AccessingDocuments.html