# Xamarin ios - Include Files in IPA

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, ipa

I want to include some images within my ipa-File, that need to be placed into the app's documents folder. A similar request was here: [Preloading Documents into iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745768/preloading-documents-into-ios-app). But I'm not familiar with Objective-C. I think I can do it some way in Xamarion.iOS, but the problem in my opinion is the quite large number of files (around 300MB). When I include the files within the AppRessources and copy them on startup, they exist twice on the disk. So there is no real saving...
Any other ideas, how i can include files without being stored twice?

Answer (score 0):

Files that you include in studio goes into your bundle. You can only read them from your application. Modifications and removing is not possible. File that you copy from bundle into your Documents folder, can be modified or removed in Document folder. So there is no way to removing files from a bundle, even if you copy them into Document folder.

You can use on demand resources to download them later intro your app:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/tvos/application-fundamentals/resources-data-storage/#On-Demand-Resources